# How to find the most frequent number and its frequency in an array in range L,R most efficiently?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, logic

Lets say we are given an array `A[]` of length `N` and we have to answer `Q` queries which consists of two integers `L,R`. We have to find the number from `A[L]` to `A[R]` which has its frequency at least `(R-L+1)/2`. If such number doesn't exist then we have to print "No such number"

I could think of only `O(Q*(R-L))` approach of running a frequency counter and first obtaining the most frequent number in the array from `L to R`. Then count its frequency.

But more optimization is needed.

**Constraints:** `1<= N <= 3*10^5`, ,`1<=Q<=10^5` ,`1<=L<=R<=N`

Comment: What is lower and upper bound of N @Shantunu

Comment: 1<= N <= 3*10^5,
,1<=Q<=10^5
,1<=L<=R<=N

Comment: Can you link to the original problem statement?

Comment: Also think about randomization: If you pick an element at random in the range L..R, it will be the number you're looking for with prob. 1/2. If you chose k random elements, the probability that the solution is not amongst them (if it exists) is 2^-k. So the problem reduces to counting frequency of a given number in a given range. This leads to O(log^2 n) per query

Comment: @ShantanuSingh: Each element in the array is of what order??

Comment: 1<= A[i] <=10^4

Comment: @ShantanuSingh: Can you give me the actual question link??

Comment: @User_Targaryen: not really as it was there on an interview test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know an `O((N + Q) * sqrt(N))` solution:

1. Let's call a number heavy if at occurs at least `B` times in the array. There are at most `N / B` heavy numbers in the array.
2. If the query segment is "short" (`R - L + 1 < 2 * B`), we can answer it in `O(B)` time (by simply iterating over all elements of the range).
3. If the query segment is "long" (`R - L + 1 >= 2 * B`), a frequent element must be heavy. We can iterate over all heavy numbers and check if at least one then fits (to do that, we can precompute prefix sums of number of occurrences for each heavy element and find the number of its occurrences in a `[L, R]` segment in constant time).

If we set `B = C * sqrt(N)` for some constant `C`, this solution runs in `O((N + Q) * sqrt(N))` time and uses `O(N * sqrt(N))` memory. With properly chosen `C`, and may fit into time and memory limit.

There is also a randomized solution which runs in `O(N + Q * log N * k)` time.

1. Let's store a vector of position of occurrences for each unique element in the array. Now we can find the number of occurrences of a fixed element  in a fixed range in `O(log N)` time (two binary searches over the vector of occurrences).
2. For each query, we'll do the following:

   - pick a random element from the segment
   - Check the number of its occurrences in `O(log N)` time as described above
   - If it's frequent enough, we are done. Otherwise, we pick another random element and do the same
   - If a frequent element exists, the probability not to pick it is no more than `1 / 2` for each trial. If we do it `k` times, the probability not to find it is `(1 / 2) ^ k`

With a proper choice of `k` (so that `O(k * log N)` per query is fast enough and `(1 / 2) ^ k` is reasonably small), this solution should pass.

Both solutions are easy to code (the first just needs prefix sums, the second only uses a vector of occurrences and binary search). If I had to code one them, I'd pick the latter (the former can be more painful to squeeze in time and memory limit).

Comment: Your solutions are good just one thing,in the 2nd solution do we have to find k by hit & trial or there is some method to get that also ?

Comment: @ShantanuSingh It sort of hit and trial (because we can always fail with some probability, and our goal is to pass all test cases). I would take something like k = 30 for the constraints in question (and move to, say k = 50 if it gets a wrong answer and k = 20 if it times out).

Comment: @ShantanuSingh and kraskevich, I thought this article might interest you: https://web.cs.dal.ca/~mhe/publications/icalp11_rangemajority.pdf (Range Majority in Constant Time and Linear Space. Stephane Durocher, Meng He, J. Ian Munro, Patrick K. Nicholson, and Matthew Skala)